# How to use mockito to not evaluate a method inside the testing method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spy

I am implementing a test case for a controller method. The controller method looks like below,

```
public class LoginController{
   public String register(String token){
     //some logic 
     loginService.delete(String token);
    //some logic
   return "xxxx";
   }
}
```

I am implementing the test case to test the register method and i do not want the method delete to be evaluated. (The delete method is a service method that returns a void). I did a bit of research and used the below code in my test method to not evaluate the delete method, but still when i debug it goes inside the delete method. Can anyone point put me out what wrong I have done.

```
public class LoginControllerTest{
   private loginService loginServiceMock;

   @Test
   public void testRegister(){
      loginServiceMock = new loginServiceImpl();
      loginService spy = spy(loginServiceMock);
      doNothing().when(spy).delete(any(String.class));
      //calling the controller method 
   }
}
```

Comment: btw. there's anyString() matcher in 'org.mockito.Matchers'. Use that instead of any(String.class). Cleaner and faster. You can check in sourceCode that returnString() is much simpler than returnFor(Class<T> clazz) in org.mockito.internal.progress.HandyReturnValues

Comment: @Anna, is the `delete` method of the `LoginService` class final?  Or is the class itself final?  Either of those two conditions would prevent that method from being stubbed in the way you intend.

Comment: @DavidWallace Nope none are final

Comment: OK, how are you injecting your spy object into the `LoginController`? Can you please show the part of the test where the `LoginController` gets created, and the `LoginService` gets added to it?

Comment: Look at never() method in Mockito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing should work as long as `loginService spy` object is injected into `LoginController` that you are testing. This is not visible from the code you've posted.

There are 2 reasons that would make the controller call the real login service method :

1. You forgot to inject the spy into the controller: something like `loginControllerToTest = new LoginController(spy)` or `loginControllerToTest.setLoginService(spy)`.
2. `loginService.delete()` is a static method in which case you need to either refactor your code to remove static dependency or use a different mocking tool such as powermock. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914433/mocking-a-singleton-with-mockito/38915148#38915148) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor `LoginController` to something like

```
public class LoginController {
    private LoginService loginService;

    public LoginController(LoginService loginService) {
        this.loginService = loginService;
    }

    public String register(String token){
        //some logic 
        loginService.delete(token);
        //some logic
        return "xxxx";
    }
 }

 public interface LoginService {
     void delete(String token);
 }
```

And then in your test

```
public class LoginControllerTest {
   private LoginController loginController;

   @Test
   public void testRegister(){
      loginController = new LoginController(t -> {});

      loginController.register("foo");

      //do some assertion
   }
}
```

I know that's not the kind of solution you (maybe) would have expected but it solves your problem (the real `delete` is not called anymore).

Other advantages with this solution:

- The code is more decoupled, more maintainable
- Direct consequence of above: the code becomes easier to test
- Direct consequence of above: you don't need to do complicated stuff that requires a mock anymore

Answer (score 0):

Whole idea of `spy` is, it allows you to invoke and verify methods on actual instances. So if you invoke a spied instance method it actually invokes the method on actual instance unless it is mocked.

For your case you need to use `mock` instead of `spy`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginControllerTest{

   @InjectMocks
   private LoginController controller;

   @Mock
   private loginService loginServiceMock; 


   @Test
   public void testRegister(){      

      doNothing().when(loginServiceMock).delete(anyString()));
      //calling the controller method 
      String value = controller.register("mytoken");
      verify(loginServiceMock,times(1)).delete(anyString());
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but when testing the register method, still it goes inside the delete method :(

Comment: @Anna can you update your full test class in question, and have you annotated your  test class with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) ?

Comment: yes I have. My other tests runs fine. The class is quite huge, that is why i simplified and added only the necessary code snippets