# Mockito is calling real method and thenReturn does not work

Tags: junit, mockito

I have read some post about it but nothing solved my problem. I have a class which is singleton and one method of this class is being called inside another class. I need to mock this method call.

```
Class SingletonClass
{
     public static SingletonClass instance()
     {
           ......
           return instance;
     }

     public boolean methodToBeMocked(Object obj)
     {
          return false;
     }
}
```

And the another class is :

```
Class A
{
      Object doSomeStuff()
      {
            ......
            boolean result = SingletonClass.instance.methodToBeMocked();
      }
}
```

And I am mocking the method methodToBeMocked in my test class. I have tried to use doReturn instead of thenReturn as it is suggested in other posts but it did not help.

My test class is :

```
Class TestClass{

     Class A a = new A();

     public void test()
     {
          SingletonClass singletonClass = mock(SingletonClass.class);
          doReturn(true).when(singletonClass).methodToBeMocked(any());

          a.doSomeStuff(); // here mocked method returns false

          // but if I do this below it returns true !!!!
          Object obj = new Object();
          boolean result = singletonClass.mockedMethod(obj);
     }
}
```

So why I am not getting true when a.doSomeStuff is called ? What is wrong here ?

Comment: Found the answer here, mocking singleton. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914433/mocking-a-singleton-with-mockito

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking a singleton with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914433/mocking-a-singleton-with-mockito)

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of others, I was using the following mock with the expectation it would not call someMock.someMethod(), unlike the when(someMock.someMethod()).doReturn("someString") usage.

```
Mockito.doReturn("someString").when(someMock).someMethod();
```

I could not understand why the real someMethod() was still being called.  It turns out the method was specified as ***final***.  Mockito can't mock static or final methods.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the static method `public static SingletonClass instance()`. The standard mockito library does not support mocking of static methods. I seen two solutions.

1. You can rewrite small your code as:

> Add new method getSingletonClassInstance() to be mocked in test

```
Class A {
       Object doSomeStuff()
       {
             ......
             boolean result = getSingletonClassInstance();
       }

       SingletonClass getSingletonClassInstance(){
             return SingletonClass.instance.methodToBeMocked();
       } 
}
```

> use spy from mockito library to create an instance of Class A

import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
.....

```
Class TestClass{

     public void test()
     {
          Class A a = spy(new A());
          SingletonClass singletonClass = mock(SingletonClass.class);
          doReturn(true).when(singletonClass).methodToBeMocked(any());

          doReturn(singletonClass).when(a).getSingletonClassInstance();

          a.doSomeStuff(); // here mocked method returns false

          // but if I do this below it returns true !!!!
          Object obj = new Object();
          boolean result = singletonClass.mockedMethod(obj);
     }
  }
```

More information about the [spy](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy) in mockito. Spy used real instance and invoke real method but provide a functionality to mock specific method. Don't worry about the others method they will continue to work with real implementation, only mocked method will be affected.

2. You can use [power mockito](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock) to mock the `public static SingletonClass
   instance()`