# Why Mockito is calling real method?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, singleton

I have a class **Service** that calls a method of singleton class. I would like to mock a **saveContract** method calls.

```java
public class Service {
    public Contract save(Contract contract) {
        Contract result;
        ...
        result = ContractDao.getInstance().saveContract(contract);
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

I modified Service class like this (added a field and a constructor, for testing purposes only):

```java
public class Service {
    private final ContractDao contractDao;
    
    public Service() {
        this(ContractDao.getInstance());
    }
    
    public Service(final ContractDao contractDao) {
        this.contractDao = contractDao;
    }
    
    public Contract save(Contract contract) {...}
}
```

And my test class is:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ServiceTest {
    @Mock
    ContractDAO contractDaoMock;
    
    private Service service;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        service = new Service(contractDaoMock);
    }
    
    @Test
    void saveContractTest() {
        Contract changedContract = new Contract(...);
        when(contractDaoMock.saveContract(any())).thenReturn(changedContract);
    
        Contract givenContract = new Contract(...);
        Contract actualContract = service.save(givenContract);
    
        //Assertions
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Comment: No. I have no reasons to use PowerMockito. I did it as described here: [Mocking a singleton with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914433/mocking-a-singleton-with-mockito)

Comment: No you don't. You never mocked `ContractDao.getInstance()`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @ChrisCross `result = ContractDao.getInstance().saveContract(Contract contract);` is calling in your test. So you shoul change your implementation of `Service` and use initialized `ContractDAO` field or you should mock `ContractDao.getInstance()`

Comment: `result = ContractDao.getInstance().saveContract(Contract contract);` is calling in service and **not** in test.

Answer (score 1):

Add `mockito-inline` dependency and use the `MockedStatic` to mock the `getInstance()` method.

Your code should look like that:

```java
    @Test
    void saveContractTest() {
        Contract changedContract = new Contract(...);
        try (MockedStatic<ContractDAO> mockedContractDAO = mockStatic(ContractDAO.class) {
            mockedContractDAO.when(ContractDAO::getInstance).thenReturn(contractDaoMock);
            when(contractDaoMock.saveContract(any())).thenReturn(changedContract);
    
            Contract givenContract = new Contract(...);
            Contract actualContract = service.save(givenContract);
    
            //Assertions
            ...
        }
    }
```

Check the docs here to know a bit more about mocking static methods: https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.9.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i found the right solution.

Comment: Please, post an answer with that, so we can help others with the same issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

In **Service.save()** I have not replaced the line

```
result = ContractDao.getInstance().saveContract(contract);
```

with line

```
result = contractDao.saveContract(contract);
```

So, we need to use a field instance which we mocked and not the singleton.getInstance().

Comment: I was inattentive and did that mistake.